# Confusion on theorem 8.1.2 and corollary in Wald's GR book

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, causality, topology

In Wald's GR book theorem 8.1.2 says:

> Let $(M,g_{ab})$ be an arbitray spacetime, and let $p \in M$. Then
> there exists a convex normal neighborhood of $p$, i.e., an open set
> $U$ such that for all $q,r \in U$ there exists a unique geodesic
> $\gamma$ connecting $q$ and $r$ and staying entirely in $U$.
> Furthermore, for any such $U$, $I^+(p)|_U$ consists of all points
> reached by future directed timelike geodesic starting from $p$ and
> contained within $U$, where $I^+(p)|_U$ denotes the chronological
> future of $p$ in the spacetime $(U,g_{ab})$. In addition, $\dot I^+(p)|_U$ is generated by the future directed null geodesics in $U$
> emanating from $p$.

In the next paragraph, it says if $q \in J^+(p)$, we can connect $p,q$ via causal curve $\lambda$  and cover this $\lambda$ by finitely many $U$'s in the theorem ($\lambda$ failed to be null geodesic in any such $U$), and we can deform each piece such that $\lambda$ becomes a timelike curve.

the corollary is:

> If $q \in J^+(p)-I^+(p)$, then any causal curve connecting $p$ to $q$
> must be a null geodesic.

My questions are:

1. How to deform this $\lambda$ to a timelike curve by theorem? Why is the condition "$λ$ failed to be null geodesic in any such $U$" assumed? Is it a piecewise differentiable one after deformation?
2. How to conclude the corollary?

Answer (score 3):

1. $\lambda$ is a future directed timelike curve when the timelike vector field chosen to time-orient the manifold $M$ does not become 0 at any point on the curve:

\begin{equation}
t^{a}(s) \neq 0 \, \, , \quad \forall \, s \in \lambda
\end{equation}

This in general isn't true for every point on a causal curve, but we want all convex normal neighbourhoods between $p$ and $q$ to contain such points so that we deform $\lambda$ to include them.

As per the theorem, each convex neighbourhood contains all points on $I^{+}(p) |_{U}$ which can be reached by a future timelike geodesic starting from point $p$. Since there is a unique geodesic within each neighbourhood that stays entirely within it and it is not null, the unique geodesic for each neighbourhood $U_{i}$ that has a set of starting/ending points $(p_{i},q_{i})$ is going to be timelike and containg points from $I^{+}(p_{i}) |_{U_{i}}$. That means one can change $\lambda$ within each neighbourhood while staying within it so that $t^{a}$ never becomes 0, making the new curve future oriented timelike.

It is now clear why the initial assumption is made. If $\lambda$ contained some neighbourhood $\mathcal{U}$ where the unique geodesic that stays entirely within it is null, then you cannot always connect its starting/ending points $(\mathcal{P}, \mathcal{Q})$ with points entirely from $I^{+}(\mathcal{P}) |_{\mathcal{U}}$ without treading outside the neighbourhood. By extension, you cannot deform $\lambda$ to become timelike as a whole. Or to put it more rigorously, you could deform $\lambda$ for all points in the chronological past of $\mathcal{P}$ into a timelike curve $\ell(p)$ and all points of its chronological future into $\overline{\ell(p)}$, but $q \notin \ell(p)$ while $q \in \overline{\ell(p)}$. Hence the resulting deformed curve would not be closed.

Since the deformation is smooth, the curve is smooth itself, not piecewise differentiable.

2. Again by virtue of the theorem, each null geodesic starting from a point $p_{i}$ at some neighbourhood will generate the boundary $\dot{I}^{+}(p_{i}) |_{U_{i}}$. By extension, if a point $s_{i}$ within this neighbourhood belongs to $\dot{I}^{+}(p_{i}) |_{U_{i}}$, that means it will be part of a null geodesic. The connection of each local null geodesic will complete a total null geodesic which will end up at the boundary $\dot{I}^{+}(p)$ for the complete curve. That boundary will be located on the lightcone that separates $I^{+}(p)$ from the rest of the causal future of $p$.

Now we suppose that $q \in J^{+}(p) - I^{+}(p)$. That means $q$ is part of a set that is generated by removing all points that are not causally accessible from the causal curve $\lambda$, therefore $q$ has to lie somewhere on the lightcone. Within this point's neighbourhood, $q$ not only belongs, but it is the ending point of a local null geodesic, hence the unique geodesic of that neighbourhood is null and not timelike. Using the conclusion from the previous paragraph, the condition that $\lambda$ is a closed curve, and the fact that $\lambda$ in this case cannot be deformed into a timelike curve, the total causal curve has to be a null geodesic.